# Using Int 13H to Read disk parameters

Tags: assembly, interrupt, hard-drive, bios

My goal is to, simply put, use Int 13h to read my disk parameters.

I understand this can not be directly accomplished in Windows, as it essentially intercepts the BIOS call.

My thinking, thus far, is that I can rewrite the code in memory location at 0x7C00h, and utilize Int 19h to do a warm reboot, which would jump to the now overwritten 0:7C00h, and then I would be able to read the disk parameters.

Am I on the right track? I feel like (I hope) I'm at least pointing in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using int 0x13 if you're on Windows? Just look issue an ATA_IDENTIFY to the ATA devices and you'll get much better information.

Comment: This is part of an assignment which specifies I write a real mode program and use int 13h, which is why I'm asking if I'm on the right track, as opposed to code. I'm fairly new to this so I'm not 100% on the best approach, the Windows isn't specified, I just thought that may be a plausible direction.

Comment: Do you have to do it from inside Windows?

Comment: The question format was vague on that, now the Prof is just saying use MSDOS in VirtualBox. Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much point in doing a warm reboot.

If your program is running under Windows, you won't be able to initiate a warm reboot and address 0x7c00 will unlikely map onto the physical memory at physical address 0x7c00, thanks to Windows.

If your program is running under DOS, why not just use `int 13h` directly without making any reboots?

If you really want to run your code on a clean system (no DOS or Windows), write a boot sector, make a bootable floppy or CD or flash stick and boot from it.